# Make current comment on a WordPress post active

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Bootstrap carousel to display 3 comments of a specific post in WordPress and the latest comment must have the `active` class on the div. However, the code that I have adds the `active` class to all 3 comments. Hence, all 3 shows in a single carousel block, where it should be divided or paginated by 3. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'status'  => 'approve',
    'number'  => '1',
    'post_id' => 9,
    'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order'   => 'DESC'
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
    echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <span class="fad fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
            comment_text();
            echo '<div id="image-caption">&mdash; <a href="'.$comment->comment_author_url.'" target="_blank">'.$comment->comment_author.'</a></div>
        </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
    </div><!-- carousel-item -->';
endforeach;
?>
```

I would like to have a condition where `if comment is latest, add $active = ' active'; else, show nothing` to the `<div class="carousel-item'.$active.'">`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go... Use for instead of foreach and check if that is the first item ($i==0)

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'status'  => 'approve',
    'number'  => '1',
    'post_id' => 9,
    'orderby' => 'comment_date',
    'order'   => 'DESC'
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );

for($i=0; $i<count($comments); $i++ ) :
    $comment = $comments[$i];
    echo '<div class="carousel-item ' . ($i==0 ? "active" : "") . '">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <span class="fad fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
            comment_text();
            echo '<div id="image-caption">&mdash; <a href="'.$comment->comment_author_url.'" target="_blank">'.$comment->comment_author.'</a></div>
        </div><!-- carousel-caption -->
    </div><!-- carousel-item -->';
endfor;
?>
```